# Фотография не выводится smarty

Tags: php, html, smarty

Вывожу аватарку в чате, картинка пишется в базу данных в формате `base64`. В скрипте в отладке вывод работает. Я вывожу так:

```
$img64ava = curl_chat($web_photoava ."/$get_pathava");// прописали путь
$img_msg= 'data:image/JPG;base64,' . base64_encode($img64ava); 
echo "<img src=$img_msg />" ; //вывели фотку
```

Записываю в базу данных так:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO shouts (shout_id, img_msg, shout_name, shout_message, shout_tg_id, shout_tg_offset, shout_date) VALUE ('', '$img_msg', '$shout_name', '$shout_message', '$shout_tg_id', '$shout_tg_offset', NOW())";
$mysqli->query($sql);
```

далее в `index.php` подключил вывод в шаблон, написав

```
$smarty->assign('img_msg', $img_msg);
```

Затем в сам шаблон `chat.tpl` в ссылку написал `{$img_msg}`, но картинка не появилась, я не понимаю почему так, я после залез в базу данных и записанное значение в таблице вставил в ссылку напрямую и фотография отобразилась[image: бд]

Вот сам шаблон:

```
{foreach from=$shouts item=val}
<div class='row w-100 rel p-0 m-0 mb-2' id='shout{$val.shout_id}'>
    <div class="col-3 text-right">
        <div class="">
            <img src="{$val.img_msg}" alt="На голубом фоне смайлик" width="50" height="50" class="avatarka">
        </div>
```

Comment: почему вы в шаблон передатеет `assign('img_msg', ...)` а выводите циклом `$val.img_msg` ?

Comment: Да я разобрался, в шаблон вывод не нужно делать, потому что мы вытягиваем из базы данных, вывожу циклом, потому что item=val (берём общее значение массива и к нему через точку добавляем массив который нужно вывести) массив не выводился потому что не был прописан класс

Comment: Это помогло function shouts_array($row){
global $users, $dateformat, $offset;
    $shouts_array = Array('shout_id'        => $row['shout_id'],
    'img_msg'       => $row['img_msg'],